Character Rig - Knees Bending Incorrectly
I've been working on a custom character rig for my online image for the past while now, and I've managed to model my character with a decently working rig and somewhat-reasonable control blocks following this tutorial online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=1khSuB6sER0.
However, the problem occurs when I go to bend the knees using the IK constraint on the feet, where the knees bend inwards despite me having pole targets to prevent that.  Moving the pole targets moves the knees side to side, but the bones themselves remain pointed inwards.  In other words, the bones do not hinge properly like they should.
It's a little difficult to explain in words, so below are images and a copy of my blender file representing the overall model/rig (please forgive the control blocks, I have little knowledge on rigging so they may be abysmal lol), the model with its knees bent, a leg moved backwards, and the overall bones respectively;




I don't understand what is causing these problems.  The closest source I can think of may be an inherent flaw in the model itself causing these problems, but I am unsure.  I also would rather not have to re-group the model again, I do not have the knowledge or experience to do something like that in this stage of the project and it would be tedious for me to redo all of this work only to find that it may not be the problem.
This is a copy of my blender file:

P.S.  If there looks like there are missing bones like ones in the kneck or segmented spine bones, those are likely on purpose for the level of animation capability I want (rigid body structure with the head being able to move everywhere, amost like the Youtuber FUNKe's character).

please share your file, read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ if it doesn't work use another platform like workupload

Gotcha, just added the file link.

In your case, you have to lock the X axis of your calf and thigh bones.
For that, go to your Bones settings > Inverse kinematics > Lock X

That should do it, and if needed you can also tweak the Pole Angle of your IK constraint (but it doesn't seem necessary in your case).



Thanks!  I'll go fix that right now.
